# How to trigger nightwatch.js on GitHub commit?

Tags: github, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js, post-commit-hook

I want to run **e2e regression tests** when my developer colleagues **commit their code to GitHub**.

I simply cannot find a place at nightwatch.js documentation or at GitHub documentation where this scenario is described.

Any Ideas where to look at? Got a solution? A working hook?
Thanks a lot in advance!